# How can I truncate specific char[] using C

Tags: c

I receive from redis-server the next char []:

```
text = "e o 5\n\000\000\001\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\020\000\000\000"
```

And I want remove everything after '\n' to I get:

```
text = "e o 5"
```

The length from text is variable, some times I receive:

```
text = "x f 5 5 6 1\n\000\000\001\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\020\000\000\000"
```

or

```
text = "h f 5 1\n\000\000\001\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\020\000\000\000"
```

But, everytime has there is the '\n'.

How can I do it? Using C language.

Comment: If the string contains 4 characters — one backslash `'\\'` and three zero `'0'` characters — after the `'\n'` (or `'\\'` `'n'`) sequence, then there's some work to do.  If the string contains a null byte `'\000'` (more usually written `'\0'`), then the string is already truncated. You can use any string handling code and it will stop at the null bytes.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'd be willing to bet that it's merely by coincidence that those characters are `'\0'` (and that they're being viewed by a debugger such as `gdb`), so in order to avoid issues such as *heartbleed* or worse due to *uninitialised garbage*, a `'\0'` should be explicitly placed *before* any string operation is used. That's just my guess. I think an MCVE would reveal the truth for certain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try `strtok()`. `strtok()` can split a string with specific delimiter.

```
String: xxx\nyyy\nzzz 
Delimiter: \n
Output: 
        xxx
        yyy
        zzz
```

Suppose `buff` is a `char *` variable which points at a writable memory area.

```
char *buff = malloc(sizeof(BUFF_SIZE));
// Or char buff[BUFF_SIZE];

// Load data into buff

// split buff with `\n`
char *token;
token = strtok(buff, "\n");
if (token)
{
    printf("First substring split by newline: %s\n", token);
}
while (token = strtok(NULL, "\n"))
{
    printf("Next substring split by newline: %s\n", token);
}
```

See more detail about `strtok()`, just type `man strtok`.

Answer (score 0):

Just place a `\0` at the end of the data the interests you:

```
strchr(text, '\n')[1] = '\0';
```

Comment: `strchr` returns a pointer, not an integer...

Comment: [Error] invalid types 'char*[char*]' for array subscript

Comment: ... and I'd suggest that you can't rely upon the data being received by the socket to be a *string*, either, as `recv` doesn't produce *strings*.

Comment: I know, but suppose that everytime is a string...

Comment: @user1989425 arg, right. Too early for my blood :-( Edited and fixed

Comment: @DimmyMagalhães see my edited answer.

Comment: The received contents might not necessarily contain `'\n'`, in which case this code is likely to segfault. In addition to that, you can't assume it's a string just because the examples shown have zero characters; those zero characters may be *uninitialised garbage*...

Comment: What?  The OP specifically stated that "But, everytime has there is the '\n'.".  If the OP and/or us have been misled and a misuse of recv() may result in an array of chars with no '\n' then, so what?  We cannot start speculating wildly about code we cannot see.  If OP's app then blows up repeatedly, it's on them.

Comment: Well, technically, what we see could most certainly be a lie as we haven't been given an MCVE (which has likely prompted the 3 close votes)... That aside, we shouldn't assume the network will always be *friendly* just out of optimism; *hackers will try to break your code*. So really, ignoring the `NULL` return values is *never* acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

When receiving from a socket you may get as a the return value from `recv` either `-1` (which denotes an error condition) or the length of the data received.

```
ssize_t length = recv(sockfd, buffer, sizeof (buffer) - 1, 0);
if (length == -1) {
    /* handle error condition */
}
```

From there you may wish to use `length` to transform your buffer into a string:

```
buffer[length] = '\0';
```

Then you can use `strchr` (among other methods) to find the `'\n'` and place a string terminator:

**Using `strchr`**

```
char *newline_ptr = strchr(buffer, '\n');
if (newline_ptr == NULL) {
    /* No newline found */
}
else {
    *newline_ptr = '\0';
}
```

**Using `strcspn`**

```
size_t newline_position = strcspn(buffer, "\n");
if (buffer[newline_position] == '\0') {
    /* No newline found */
}
else {
    buffer[newline_position] = '\0';
}
```

You could also use `strtok` safely from here, as described from [Joy Allens answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51007665/1989425).

I tend to prefer to use `strcspn` as during prototyping you can simply write `buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = '\0';` without risk of null pointer dereference.

As our own Jonathan Leffler noted, if your delimiters are larger than one character, you're going to need to put a lot more work to robustly tokenize on them. You might need to use `strstr` to search for them, for example.